# Manipulating Data in Django's Admin Panel prior to saving an inlined model

Tags: django, admin

I want to make changes to the data that is being saved in the admin page.
I've tried save_model. The only difficulty is that I'm using an inlined model as shown below:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Material(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type

class Prop(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s_%s" % (self.color, str(self.material))

class Pen(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    prop = models.ForeignKey(Prop)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.label, str(self.prop))

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from .models import Material, Prop, Pen


class PropInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Prop
    extra = 1

class MaterialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PropInlineAdmin,]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print obj.prop_set.values()
        obj.prop_set.color = 'Red'
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Pen)
admin.site.register(Prop)
admin.site.register(Material, MaterialAdmin)
```

Let's say the user is creating a Material object with black color.
As an example, what I'm trying to do is to change that to be "Black" with first letter capitalized.
One problem is that prop_set does not have the color property until after it is saved.
Another problem is that the change above is not taking effect.
How can I manipulate the inlined values that are being saved?

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from .models import Material, Prop, Pen


class PropInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Prop
    extra = 1

class MaterialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PropInlineAdmin,]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        for f in formset.forms:
            obj = f.instance 
            obj.color = obj.color.upper() # or whatever change you'd like
        formset.save()

admin.site.register(Pen)
admin.site.register(Prop)
admin.site.register(Material, MaterialAdmin)
```